# Duvida com Query SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela de movimento de estoque com as seguintes colunas e dados:

tabela **movimentacoes**

```
id | operacao | prodinsumo | qtde
----------------------------------
1  | 1        | 25         | 6
2  | 2        | 10         | 3
3  | 10       | 17         | 1
4  | 11       | 10         | 2
```

tabela **insumos**:

```
codinsumo | nomeinsumo
------------------------
10        | água mineral
```

tabela **produtos**:

```
codproduto | nomeproduto
---------------------------    
25         | refrigerante
17         | espetinho
```

Na coluna `operacao` ficam guardados os códigos das operações que são:

> **1 - Venda Produto**
>
> **2 - Venda Insumo**
>
> **10 - Estorno Produto**
>
> **11 - Estorno Insumo**

A coluna `prodinsumo` armazena o código do insumo ou do produto conforme a operação.

Gostaria de poder fazer uma query que coloque o nome do insumo ou do produto conforme a operação, porém não sei como fazer.

Segue uma query que fiz que serve para selecionar as colunas porém não decide de qual tabela vai pegar o nome, se é da de insumos ou produtos.

```
select
case m.operacao
  when 1 then "Venda produto"
  when 2 then "Venda insumo"
  when 10 then "Estorno produto"
  when 11 then "Estorno insumo"
end as operacao,
i.nomeinsumo as nome, -- ou p.nomeproduto as nome
m.qtde
from movimentacoes m
left join produtos p on m.prodinsumo = p.codproduto
left join insumos i on m.prodinsumo = i.codinsumo
```

Eu preciso que quando a coluna `operacao` estiver com os valores `1` ou `10` a coluna `nome` seja com o valor da coluna `nomeproduto` da tabela `produtos` e quando estiver com o valores `2` ou `11` seja com o valor da coluna `nomeinsumo` da tabela `insumos`.

Comment: Coloca seu schema no sqlfiddle, assim ajuda a gente já te mandar a query pronta. Mas enfim, para utilizar essa lógica, você pode usar o https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html quando o valor for x, faz um subselect, se não, outro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após a resposta do @PedroE. consegui fazer a query abaixo que resolveu o problema de uma forma melhor.

Esta query está levando em consideração que, quando não forem encontradas as operações dos produtos as operações serão de insumos, pois não existem outras operações a não ser essas que estão na questão.

```
select
case m.operacao
  when 1 then "Venda produto"
  when 2 then "Venda insumo"
  when 10 then "Estorno produto"
  when 11 then "Estorno insumo"
end as operacao,
case m.operacao
  when 1 then p.nomeproduto
  when 10 then p.nomeproduto
  else i.nomeinsumo
end as nome, 
m.qtde
from movimentacoes m
left join produtos p on m.prodinsumo = p.codproduto
left join insumos i on m.prodinsumo = i.codinsumo
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta com o SQL abaixo, lembrando que o resultado do select do nome deve sempre retornar apenas 1 valor, por isso do LIMIT 1.

```
select
case m.operacao
  when 1 then "Venda produto"
  when 2 then "Venda insumo"
  when 10 then "Estorno produto"
  when 11 then "Estorno insumo"
end as operacao,
case m.operacao
  when 1 then (select nomeproduto from produtos where codproduto = 1  LIMIT 1)
  when 2 then (select nomeinsumo from insumos where codinsumo = 2  LIMIT 1)
  when 10 then (select nomeproduto from produtos where codproduto = 10  LIMIT 1)
  when 11 then (select nomeinsumo from insumos where codinsumo = 11  LIMIT 1)
end as nome,
m.qtde
from movimentacoes m
left join produtos p on m.prodinsumo = p.codproduto
left join insumos i on m.prodinsumo = i.codinsumo
```

Comment: Amigo, dei voto a favor na sua resposta pois ela me ajudou a resolver o problema, fiz de uma forma diferente que não precisou fazer os *subselects* com o `LIMIT 1`.